# Can I make a new Windows 7 installation act like an existing one on the same computer?

Tags: windows-7

I currently have a computer with a Windows 7 installation that does not boot, and it also has an empty 25GB partition. I know the problem is in the windows partition because I can boot into a Ubuntu partition on the same hard drive. If I install Windows 7 on that second partition, can I make it behave as though it was the original partition (Libraries points to the same folder, same programs are installed, etc.) without filling the new partition past capacity?

For example, I have Steam on my original Windows 7 installation with quite a few games. Can I change some things on a new clean installation so that I can run those games on the new installation as though I was on the original?

Currently, when I try to boot into Windows I just get a black screen with a blinking text cursor, as described in [my previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/389491/windows-7-boots-to-black-screen-with-blinking-cursor).

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off figuring out why it doesn't boot? Sure you can change the references _if they still exist_, but what if it's a hardware failure or some other problem? In fact you might be better off bootling a live CD and backing up your data.

Comment: @Raystafarian I'm sorry, I guess my question was unclear about that. I can boot into a Linux partition on the same hard drive but not into Windows.

Comment: Try several Startup repairs in a row...http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/7728/troubleshot-startup-problems-with-startup-repair-tool-in-windows-7-vista/

Comment: @Moab I have asked about my problem here before: http://superuser.com/questions/389491/windows-7-boots-to-black-screen-with-blinking-cursor. Nothing I have tried has made it work, and this is just another option I am looking into.

Comment: @murgatroid99 you might put that information in your question.

Comment: @Moab I added the info