# Windows 7 fresh install, not booting but shows a black screen with blinking cursor

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, boot, partitioning

Our laptop has two OS installed: ubuntu and windows 7, and it has about 4 partitions: swap,home,root,windows 7. I moved ubuntu to the first partition before windows 7 but I don't have any problems after that. The windows 7 partition has the largest part of the disk. One day, I have to shrink my home and root partitions to give some free space to the windows 7 partition with gparted.

After all of that, Windows 7 is now unbootable in a sense that I couldn't go further the blank screen which means no safe mode, recovery, and no boot menu.

Good thing that ubuntu is still bootable via grub.

I have the original holographic installation dvd of Windows 7 Starter that came with the laptop.

I've tried all of these:

1. [Rebuilding and reinstalling bcd](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ht/rebuild-bcd-store-windows.htm)
2. formating Windows 7 partition and Install
3. Reinstalling over the existing Windows 7 installation
4. Startup Repair
5. System Restore
6. Everything mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/389491/windows-7-boots-to-black-screen-with-blinking-cursor)
7. chkdsk (it took along time)
8. Crying

**EDIT1:**
The partition looks like this:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xa7554158

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    48947199    24472576   83  Linux
/dev/sda2   *    48947200   423772159   187412480    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       423772160   621045759    98636800    5  Extended
/dev/sda4       621047808   625141759     2046976   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda5       423774208   573700095    74962944   83  Linux
```

Comment: Done! I think the Windows 7 partition is already active, does it?

Comment: Yeah it's active, see the "boot" flag set on `sda2` in your fdisk output.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do. I have my files there, plus the important small files from Windows 7. I still have some on the only NTFS partition, these are the big ones.

Comment: The easy solution would be to back up all your important files using your Ubuntu install, and then wipe the disk and reinstall windows.

Comment: I wish I could. We have slow internet about 50 kbps, no extra hard drive and just a 4gb usb drive.